# Moving objects that have been created using 'Add collection instance"

Tags: transforms, collections, instances

I've created a model of an octagonal gazebo by creating objects then using "Add Collection Instance" to duplicate objects and then rotating.  The creation went great until I went to move the entire gazebo.  For the life of me, I can't figure it out.  Is there a way to move the entire model including original objects and instances?  Here is a link to a basic blend file depicting what I did with a cube duplicated and rotated.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1mvyGi8goerBRDitDOpIBvyYbekmWJ5Z_?usp=sharing

Any help would be appreciated.

tc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you move the original at the same time as the instances, the instances will move twice, because their location will also depend on the location of the original relatively to the world space. So first deactivate the original, and then select the instances and move them:

[image]

Comment: 99.6k... getting close :))

Comment: ah ah yes, still far from Gandalf3 though  ^^

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. So, I'm guessing from your reply that moving the original object and maintaining the transforms of the instances is not possible.

Comment: as soon as you'll move the original it will move the instances, yes